# About android lifecycle

Tags: android

I read about the android activity's life cycle from here [Dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html). Now i have confusions that which part of code resides in which method, like onCreate, onStart, onResume, onRestart, onPause, onResume, onStop and onDestroy. Can you help me to put them in right place. Also the tracking should continue even when the application is minimized. I have the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  LocationListener {

//List of user defined variables

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /*for now i  have kept everything in onCreate method
     * i have start and stop button to start the tracking and stop the tracking and show the distance of travel
    1. Checking whether GPS is on or OFF
    2. button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    3. Code to load the Google map
    4. Now specified what start and stop button does.
        i. when i press start button it starts overlaying the path in the map and calculate distance travelled so far
        ii. when i press stop button it stops tracking and shows the details of final result in next activity.
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 2, this);
    */

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //i hace code for tracking and overlaying here

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Who said you should listen for location updates only in Activities? What if you have a separate Service for that or a dedicated model object. Make sure you read [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) also.

Comment: It all depends what do you want to do in your app. Do you want to listen for GPS locations while in background or only in foreground?

Comment: I want to listen for GPS for both background and foreground.

Comment: See also this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: Then you should use a Service for it and not a Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the idea I think you want: "An app that has a start record and stop record button, meanwhile displays the route using google maps."
Correct?

You will need 2 components:

**Service** (Background operations)

- When started: listens for GPS updates and stores them internally.
- When stopped: stop listening

**Activity** (GUI)

Has 2 buttons, start and stop recording, and Google Maps Widget.

- On button start: use `startService` to start the `Service`
- On button stop: use `stopService` to stop the `Service`
- Location retrieving (between `onResume` and `onPause`): ask the Service (using binding or Messager) about the interally stored locations. When retrieved, show them with Google Maps widget.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want. Can you help me with some code or any links for tutorial for using service(background operations). Can u tell me which code resides in which method exactly.

Comment: This behaviour is explained in any tutorial you can find. Look on d.android.com and http://www.vogella.com/android.html

Comment: starting the service in onPause() making the service to do some work and send the data to calling activity periodically and stop the service in onResume(). Will this work? Since activity in background cannot run any code, how will activity get the message from service ?

Comment: You should start service when clicking on the buttons, not in onPause of onResume of Activity.